# Receber um array de datas diferente da escolhida

Tags: javascript, jquery

Possuo um formulário, onde preciso escolher as datas, que no caso seriam múltiplas.

Estou usando este plugin/componente JQuery: http://multidatespickr.sourceforge.net/

Meu problema é que não quero salvar as datas escolhidas e sim as não marcadas.

Exemplo bem simples:

> escolho 10/10/2016

Tenho que receber no meu input text:

> 01/10/2016, 02/10/2016... com exceção do 10/10/2016.

Código:
http://jsfiddle.net/3t4j9/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Faz um ciclo for para correr as datas todas do dado mês e filtra as que não queres.

Para isso precisas de um `onSelect` nas opções do plugin, como callback da mudança de valores.

Ficaria assim:

```
$('#datePick').multiDatesPicker({
  dateFormat: "yy-m-d", // para ter ano com 4 casas
  onSelect: function(str) {
    var arrayDeDatas = this.value.split(',').map(function(str) {
      return str.trim();
    });
    var invertidas = inverterEscolha(arrayDeDatas);
    alert(JSON.stringify(invertidas, null, 4)); // só para o exemplo
  }
});

function dataFormatada(d) {
  return [d.getFullYear(), d.getMonth() + 1, d.getDate()].join('-');
}

function inverterEscolha(datas) {
  var inicio = datas.slice(0, 1)[0].split('-').map(Number);
  var fim = datas.slice(-1)[0].split('-').map(Number);
  var data = new Date(inicio[0], inicio[1] - 1); // esta data vai sendo mudada dentro do loop
  var limite = new Date(fim[0], fim[1], 0); // ultimo dia do mês escolhido
  var datasInvertidas = [];
  var contador = 0;
  while (data < limite) {
    contador++;
    data = new Date(inicio[0], inicio[1] - 1, contador);
    var str = dataFormatada(data);
    if (datas.indexOf(str) == -1) datasInvertidas.push(data);
  }
  return datasInvertidas.map(dataFormatada);
}
```

#### jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/s6Lv85wz/

Comment: Muito obrigada @Sergio. Isso mesmo que eu desejava. Ótima semana a todos!

Answer (score 0):

Você pode checar o click do seu botão de submit, no caso trocar por um link (), obter as datas que foram selecionadas no input e checa-las num loop as datas que quer captar, ao final chamar o submit do form. Abaixo está uma função para checar o último dia do mês que pode ajudar nesta lógica.

```
    function daysInMonth(month,year) {
        var m = [31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31];
       if (month != 2) return m[month - 1];
       if (year % 4 != 0) return m[1];
       if (year % 100 == 0 && year%400 != 0) return m[1];
       return m[1] + 1;
    }
```